Google Sheets ARRAYFORMULA to find the submission date of the previous similar report
Based on the data in this sheet, can you help me make a formula to find the data from A of the  previous Fire report for the same location?
In other words, I need to find the previous Timestamp of the entry with the same Location as the current row's Location in column E and the same Report Type in column F. I only need this functionality for the Fire reports, so it is fine if the static value "Fire" is used for matching col F. It is also fine if the formula returns the date of the previous report for Lockdown and Torndao reports are well.
Data is coming from a Google Form so I need the formula to go in G2 and use ARRAYFORMULA or something similar so that it automatically populates the new rows made by the form submissions. Row 2 is frozen specifically for this purpose.
I believe the problem I am running into is based on the ARRAYFORMULA handles data and specifically that it does not play well with QUERY or FILTER.
I have tried a number of things including SORT, FILTER, LARGE, row “filtering” using ROW(A2:A)<ROW(A2:A), “filtering” the data using IF (with AND and/or nested IFs). Here is one example:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="", "", IF(F2:F="Fire", INDEX(A$2:A, MATCH(TRUE, AND((E$2:E=E2:E),(F$2:F=F2:F),(A$2:A<A2:A), 0))), "")))

In general I am getting one of 3 results:
Date 0 (1/1/1899)
The first matching date entry (8/14/2024 0:00:00 in the data provided) for most if not all entries
Something along the lines of a "no match found" error.
Expected date values can be found in the sheet in col I.


You may try:
=map(E3:E,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,xlookup(Σ&offset(Σ,,1),index(E2:offset(Σ,-1,)&F2:index(F:F,row(Σ)-1)),A2:index(A:A,row(Σ)-1),,,-1))))



Maybe a bit simpler but admittedly less efficient as it is searching all rows:
=ArrayFormula(map(E3:E,F3:F,lambda(e,f,xlookup(1,(E3:E=E)*(F3:F=F)*(row(A3:A)<row(E)),A3:A,"",0,-1))))


or alternatively
=ArrayFormula(map(A3:A,E3:E,F3:F,lambda(a_,e_,f_,xlookup(1,(E3:E_=E_)*(F3:F_=F_)*(row(A3:A_)<row(A_)),A3:A_,"",0,-1))))


Another solution:
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAP(A3:A,E3:E,F3:F,LAMBDA(α,β,γ,
     IF(ROW(α)=3,,
       XLOOKUP(
         β&γ,
         E3:OFFSET(β,-1,)&F3:OFFSET(γ,-1,),
         A3:OFFSET(α,-1,),,,-1)))))

